# Potential bug in tensorflow CNN tutorial code using ExponentialMovingAverage?

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm studying the code of the tensorflow convolution neural network tutorial which trains a CNN using the cifar10 dataset. The source code lies here in [Gihub](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10) and the document in [Document](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn).

My question is specifically about the use of `ExponentialMovingAverage`([doc here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage)) in `cifar10.py` line 375-378. which is

```
with tf.control_dependencies([apply_gradient_op, variables_averages_op]):
    train_op = tf.no_op(name='train')
return train_op
```

Here, the `variables_averages_op` is an operation that updates all the shadow variables and `apply_gradient_op` is an operation that applies computed gradients to all original variables(which updates the original variables, a.k.a. model weights).

Since `control_dependencies` doesn't guarantee the order of the execution of its passed arguments, the execution order of `apply_gradient_op` and `variables_averages_op` is arbitrary in this example, which further indicates that upon running the `train_op`, we could end up with firstly updating the original variables and then updating the corresponding shadow variables, or updating shadow variables **before** the original variables. The latter one seems unreasonable to me.

According to the official doc of `ExponentialMovingAverage`(link above), the update  of the shadow variable relies on the original variable:

`shadow_variable = decay * shadow_variable + (1 - decay) * variable`

The update of the original variable **should be before** the update of the shadow ones, which is not the case in the tutorial code.

Can anyone help me clear that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are right. It does seem like a bug in the example. It is probably not important in practice as the order of variable update and moving average update is likely to be stable. Even if it is the "wrong" order, in the worst case, your moving average will be "one step ahead of the variable". Which is likely to have a less significant effect than changing your decay from `0.999` to `0.998` or something like that.

Just created a pull request to fix this: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/3946